# Reverse Iterating Over Characters of String in C++

Tags: c++, string, size, reverse

I want to print the reverse of a string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str = "no", str1 = "yes";
    for (int i = str.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << str[i];
    for (int j = str1.size(); j >= 0; j--) //without minus one
        cout << str1[j];
}
```

What is the difference between the two loops ? 
When it gives null pointer ?

Comment: Remember that strings, arrays and vectors have ***zero-based*** indexes. A string of length `N` have indexes from `0` to `N - 1` (inclusive).

Comment: The second loop, in the first iteration, accesses `str1[str1.size()]` which is one past the end since indexing is zero based.  The behaviour is therefore undefined.   Giving different results between your compiler at home and a compiler in an exam is certainly possible when behaviour is undefined.

Comment: If you use `.at()` instead of the `[]` overload, you'll see a difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at):

[image]

So in C++11 this should be fine as it prints the null character, but in earlier versions, it could also be undefined behavior. Which means that anything could happen, including any kind of error, or even the expected behavior.

If it's working on your system but not on the system you're doing the exam on, it's probably because the exam system uses an old version where it's undefined behavior. Or it is undefined behavior on both systems but just manifests in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

@Blaze already answered why accessing `str[str.size()]` might cause problems.

One way to avoid these problems when iterating array-like is to use `iterator` - in your case `reverse_iterator` would do the trick:

```
std::string::reverse_iterator itr = str1.rbegin();

while (itr != str1.rend())
   std::cout << *itr++;
```